# how to get log file for multiple users in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
public partial class Loginform : Form
{      
    public Loginform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = "D://Login.hhh";
        if (!File.Exists(dir))
        {
            File.Create(dir);
        }

        string filePath = dir;
        string s = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
        string s1 = getIP();
        using (StreamWriter swrObj = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
        {
            swrObj.Write(s1 + "|" + s + "|" + Txtusername.Text + "|" + "user logged in on :|" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            swrObj.Write("\t\t");
            swrObj.Write("\t\t");
            swrObj.WriteLine();
            MessageBox.Show("Login success");
        }
    }

    private void Loginform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

    }
    private string getIP()
    { 
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "?";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        return  localIP;
    }

 }
```

I want to apply log file for project in C#, I am using above method to to create log file for getting system name, IP address and user login, but it is applicable in single user environment, if apply this in multi-user environment, How to get all users log info? please any one help me?

Comment: do you want to create Log file for each user separately...

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you want to create Log file for each user , then you can just do it like this:-

```
 private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s1 = getIP();
        string dir = "D://"+s1+"-"+DateTime.Now+"Login.hhh";
        if (!File.Exists(dir))
        {
            File.Create(dir);
        }

        string filePath = dir;
        string s = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");

        using (StreamWriter swrObj = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
        {
            swrObj.Write(s1 + "|" + s + "|" + Txtusername.Text + "|" + "user logged in on :|" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            swrObj.Write("\t\t");
            swrObj.Write("\t\t");
            swrObj.WriteLine();
            MessageBox.Show("Login success");
        }
    }
```